# How to test srcset algorithm

Tags: html, image, responsive, srcset, responsive-images

I'm asking this because in my Mac Retina and Google Chrome Developer Tools, I can't see the other images in my srcset.

```
<img srcset="image-415.jpg 415w,
             image-768.jpg 768w,
             image-992.jpg 992w,
             image-1440.jpg 1440w"
     src="image-1440.jpg" alt="Image">
```

It always brings the bigger image.

The tests that I'm doing are:
 - open the developer tools
 - resize my window near to the images resolution
 - refresh the page

**UPDATE**

Online example:
[Srcset](http://with.italoborg.es/lab/srcset/)

Comment: This is the problem I am having too - did you find a solution? I seem to think it might be a caching issue... but I'm not sure and so am looking for a set method for checking if srcset/sizes is working.

Comment: @Daniel, didn't find nothing. I started to think that the algorithm works fine, because the retina display everything looks like a mess hehe

Answer (score 2):

Your page is unfortunately not online anymore…

First, your code misses a `sizes` attribute, which would tell the browser which width it should render the image. This is (now) a mandatory attribute when you use the `w` descriptor in `srcset`.

Browsers will however default to `100vw` if the attribute is missing, which means the full width of the viewport.

On your Retina display, did you try to load the page in a browser with a viewport less than `700px` wide, AFTER clearing the cache?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nicolas. I solve this, but don't remember anymore because was a long time ago! hehe. I could understand what you said very clear!